# Phoenix Ecto schema for internal mailbox

Tags: database, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am building an application messaging system. I am planning on using channels for real-time notifications but I was wondering if this schema makes sense. I am looking for any constructive criticism and problems that might arise.

### message.ex

```
defmodule Trophus.Message do
  use Trophus.Web, :model

  schema "messages" do
    belongs_to :conversation, Trophus.Conversation
    field :body, :string
    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(body conversation)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  @doc """
  Creates a changeset based on the `model` and `params`.

  If no params are provided, an invalid changeset is returned
  with no validation performed.
  """
  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

### conversation.ex

```
defmodule Trophus.Conversation do
  use Trophus.Web, :model

  schema "conversations" do
    has_many :messages, Message
    belongs_to :initiator, User, foreign_key: :user_id
    belongs_to :receiver, User, foreign_key: :user_id
    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(initiator receiver)
  @optional_fields ~w(messages)

  @doc """
  Creates a changeset based on the `model` and `params`.

  If no params are provided, an invalid changeset is returned
  with no validation performed.
  """
  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```